# Running a React or Node js app in Production environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs

During developing a React app to run it and see it in action we issue npm start
or to run a node.js app we run node index.js

How is this done is a production environment.
How is the react app accessible in a prod environment.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436193/deploying-reactjs-application-in-production-with-nodejs-backend

Comment: this question has huge scope and many possible solutions. I suggest you would be best off going through some related blog posts to get a feel for the options and make some choices. https://www.google.com/search?q=react+node+production Unles your react app involves server side rendering it can be hosted on a static server or CDN. The node app needs to be run on a server, or cloud function/lambda. You could use a service such as Heroku or Appengine, or run your own server on a provider such as DigitalOcean.. many, many options which will depend on your scale and budget.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate node app with react app, like so the use of webpack will transpile your react app(for this you need a webpack config file link:- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75), which will be a compiled version of jsx served like a static file(say like bundle.js) called from your index.html (like say `<script type="text/javascript" src="./path to your/bundle.js"></script>`). Then running npm start command which will invoke node app.